# Outer measure induced by set function

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the following theorem from Folland's Real Analysis (proposition 1.10 page 29):

*Let $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\rho: \mathcal{E} \mapsto [0,+\infty)$ be such that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}, X \in \mathcal{E}$ and $\rho(\emptyset)=0$.
Then for any $A \subset X$ $\mu^*(A)=inf \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \rho(E_i), \forall i \ E_i \in \mathcal{E}, A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i \rbrace$ is an outermeasure.*

I kind of understand the proof except for when he proves the subadditivity:

*Suppose $\lbrace A_j \rbrace_{j=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\epsilon >0$. For each j there exists $\lbrace E_j^k \rbrace_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{E}$ such that $A_j \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_j^k$ and
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \rho(E_j^k) \leq \mu^*(A_j) +\epsilon 2^{-j}$...*

How does one know that such a sequence of sets exists?

Answer (score 1):

This is known by the very definition of $\mu^*$. $\mu^*(A_j)$ is the $\inf$ over all sums of this kind, so in the set 
$$\{\sum\rho(E_i), \forall i E_i \in {\cal{E}}, A_j \subset \cup_i E_i \} $$
you will find elements which are arbitrarily close to  $\mu^*(A_j)$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I'm thinking is that since the only restriction is that $\emptyset$ and X are in $\mathcal{E}$ I can take $\mathcal{E}=\lbrace \emptyset, X \rbrace$. How can I then find elements arbitrarily close to $\mu^*(A_j)$?

Comment: If $\mathcal{E}=\{\emptyset,X\}$, then for each non-empty subset $A$ of $X$, we have that the only such sum in the set is $\rho(X)$.

Comment: @user202542 see the comment of sqtrat. In that case you can always acchieve equlity, and again, you simply refer to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B\subseteq X$ and define $E_1=X$ and $E_i=\varnothing$ for $i=2,3,\dots$

Then $B\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ so that by definition: $$\mu^*(B)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\rho E_i=\rho(X)+0+0+\cdots=\rho(X)<\infty$$

In fact we can say that: $$0\leq\mu^*(B)=\inf S_B<\infty$$ where $S_B$ is a **non-empty** subset of $[0,\infty)$.

That means that for **any** $\delta>0$ we can find a value $s\in S_B$ with $\mu^*(B)<s\leq\mu^*(B)+\delta$.

This is applied on $B=A_j$ and $\delta=\epsilon2^{-j}>0$.